# How to ensure you execute a method only once another has been complete in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get my current location below, & then create a map which uses those co-ordinates to center the map:

```
lat;
lng;
map;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getLoc();
    this.initMap();
    this.markerService.makeCapitalMarkers(this.map);
}

getLoc() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      {
        maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 5000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }
    ).then((resp) => {
      this.lat = resp.coords.latitude
      this.lng = resp.coords.longitude
    }, er => {
      //alert("error getting location")
      alert('Can not retrieve Location')
    });
  }

private initMap(): void {
    console.log(this.lat + " : " + this.lng);
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [this.lat, this.lng],
      zoom: 3
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

`lat` and `lng` are being populated with the correct values, but they're not being populated before the map is created.

I logged them inside `initMap()` & both are coming back as undefined, but I have their values in the HTML, and they're displayed correctly on that.

The problem I think is that the map is being loaded before the co-ordinates are read. Can someone please tell me how I can make sure `getLoc()` is executed before `initMap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `getLoc()` return the promise and put the `initMap()` call in its success.

Something like:

```
lat;
lng;
map;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getLoc().then((resp) => {
      this.lat = resp.coords.latitude
      this.lng = resp.coords.longitude
      this.initMap();
      this.markerService.makeCapitalMarkers(this.map);
    }, er => {
      //alert("error getting location")
      alert('Can not retrieve Location')
    });
}

getLoc() {
    return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      {
        maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 5000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }
    );
  }

private initMap(): void {
    console.log(this.lat + " : " + this.lng);
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [this.lat, this.lng],
      zoom: 3
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

Or you could use `async` and `await` to make the code a bit tidier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I tried your code above, but I'm getting this console error  _Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)_

Comment: Sorry - missed a couple of lines just before the this.initMap(). I've edited the answer. Without a full sample, I can't really test stuff, so it's a bit trail and error.